# How to change the Menu Icon in Raspbian - no browse button in taskbar menu icon

Tags: raspbian, usb, boot, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-desktop

[![this is an example of what i deal with, idk how to take screenshots in my raspberry][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk7ru.png
i don't have a browse button, i can only type stuff there like start-here, launch & magpi, but if i use /directory/myicon.png it doesn't work, what do ya want from me, i don't know what else to ask, i did try to change menu settings, i already mention it, please just let me post my question so someone may help me, i right clicked on a place that says Click here to open applications menu, and then i choosed the Menu Settings option and a window with the header "Menu" appeared, unlike other youtube tutorials or images, there is not a browse button option, there are to text boxes, one says "Icon" and the other says "Padding", i did try to put a Path in the Icon text box, but it doesn't work, the only things that work and change the icon are "launch", "magpi" and "computer"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your post is just a wall of words without any logical grouping into sentences ... I am pretty sure that your native language has sentence structure, so there is no excuse for the mess that you presented